# Is there a major cleanup of users on different SO sites?

Tags: discussion, reputation, user-accounts

Recently I started to notice that almost every day I see -10/-5 a `user was removed` (coming from different sites). It is not just one user/but rather many different users.

I know few reasons why the user can be removed, but I am rather surprised that this started to happen really often. Is there some cleanup from old/inactive users or this is just coincidence?

Comment: Due to cleanup of all sites of Stack Exchange there is removed inactive users and where related votes and activity, you have see -10 or -5 as these activity done by those users.